# How can I convert yuv file to h264?

Tags: video, encoding, h.264, yuv

I have cif and qcif yuv image files. I want to convert them to h264 file.

Could you advise me any application or program that encode h264?

Comment: How do you want to convert an image file to a video file? And what kind of platform are you on?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [video converter library](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=video+converter+library).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use mediacoderhq.com free software. You may also need an an h264 codec. http://www.afreecodec.com/26/h264-codec/

Edit: Sorry, you said image files as source.You may need Virtualdub.org free software to get firstly an avi compiled..It can input image sequences, from the formats deployable in Open dialog.